# Why limit method is not respected in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, limit

My application, based on the Michael Hartl's tutorial, renders in the home page a collection of the user's microposts and of the microposts of the user's following through method `feed` in `user.rb`:

```
  def feed
    following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE  follower_id = :user_id"
    Micropost.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids})
                     OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id).limit(100)
  end
```

I added a limit of 100 microposts. 
Logging in the console, I checked that the limit was respected:

```
2.3.1 :003 > user.feed.count
   (1.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "microposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE  follower_id = 1)
                     OR user_id = 1) LIMIT $1) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 100]]
 => 100
```

A `@feed_item` variable is defined in the controller as follows:

```
@feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

then it is rendered into view. 
However, when I browse the page with my browser, the limit is not respected and I get all microposts (251 instead of 100, 9 pages of 30 microposts each instead of 4). Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#paginate` redefines limit and offset of the relation.

For what you want to achieve you can pass option `total_entries` to `#paginate`

`@feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page], total_entries: 100)`

Comment: It looks as if 'total_entries' calculates how many pages are necessay for 100 entries and will complete anyway all the pages. In this case 4 pages of 30 per page is 120 entries. So, even though I set total_entries: 100, I will have 120 entries.

Comment: @Asarluhi Yeah. That is how it works  Unfortunately, it seems that will_paginate doesn't offers anything beyond that. So, the only thing I could suggest is to reduce `per_page`

Comment: There is another gem for pagination `kaminari`, it is usually preferred over `will_paginate` as it is maintained better. However, it seems that neither `kaminari` nor `will_paginate` offers desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30, total_entries: 100)
```